# Loading File on DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH - is it safe with respect to the loaderlock?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, loaderlock

I want to create a dll that loads an ini file DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH. The is in the same directory as the executable loading the dll. Can this be done safely with respect to the loader lock?

regards
Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft's [best practices for DLLs](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/f/7/af7777e5-7dcd-4800-8a0a-b18336565f5b/dll_bestprac.doc&ei=7u66Ubu5Bqr40gWotoCADA&usg=AFQjCNEC6NBwgmrYFf8n8xtk5MgllXhWgQ&sig2=gdf2AXcgUkllZjhdF_uLDQ&bvm=bv.47883778,d.d2k&cad=rjt), it *is* safe to open, read and write files.

Do's and don'ts reproduced in summary below

[image]

**EDIT** following on from your clarification in comments, yes it *is* safe to call `GetModuleFileName` because, [as MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (at the bottom of the page) that function is implemented in `kernel32.dll` (see above "safe" section).

Comment: the question is more: is it safe to get the directory where the application is located. And which way is safe? Can I call "GetModuleFileName"?

Comment: @TobiasLangner yes you can call `GetModuleFileName` because it's in `kernel32.dll` (in the "safe" section above).